# Как передать в Activity данные из DialogFragment используя Interface?

Tags: java, android

В DialogFragment:

```
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    if (getActivity() instanceof OnResumeListener){
        ((OnResumeListener) getActivity()).bodyOnResume();
    }
}
```

Activity отслеживаю завершение DialogFragment:

```
@Override
public void bodyOnResume() {

}
```

Interface:

```
public interface OnResumeListener {
    public void bodyOnResume();
}
```

Как в Activity передать данные этим способом.

Comment: А чем параметр в методе интерфейса не подходит?

Comment: Сейчас попробовал еще раз и заработало! Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В целом не важно из какого фрагмента вы передаете данные в активити

Создается интерфейс

```
public interface OnResumeListener {
    public void bodyOnResume(YourObject data);
}
```

Во фрагменте вы создаете экземпляр интерфейса

```
public class Fragment extends Fragment {

    private OnResumeListener mListener;
    //some code

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mListener = (OnResumeListener) context;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_auth, container, false);
        init(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        mListener.bodyOnResume(YourObject data);
    }
}
```

А в Activity вы реализуете этот интерфейс

```
public class AuthActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnResumeListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth);

        init();
    }

    //some code

    @Override
    public void bodyOnResume(YourObject data){
        //some action with your data
    }
}
```